# how to set user privileges?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Suppose I am building an app using current mysql database tables.

I have this query (SELECT o.*,u.* FROM users u JOIN orders o ON (o.order_id = u.user_id) WHERE o.order_id = ?) to set privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add something to the `WHERE` clause in view_order.php that matches the `user_id` of the logged in user to the order - that will let a user just see their own orders. If you want to give admins the ability to see, everything:

```
SELECT 
o.*,u.* 
FROM 
users u JOIN orders o ON (o.user_id = u.user_id) 
WHERE 
o.order_id = ? AND (o.user_id=? OR u.privileges='ADMIN')
```

At least something like that - you'll have to tweak it slightly, as I've no idea how your tracking the details of the logged in user.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! what do you mean by how to track details of the user?

Comment: When someone logs into the website, you're presumably tracking their login somewhere, in a cookie or a session